# how to create a folder for my mobile application in the storage using react-native

Tags: android, react-native

Am making an android application using react-native. The application is supposed to have its own separate folder in the phone to help save all the books and content that the user bought from the application. i also need to hide the folder or kind of encrypt it so the user doesn't share his own books or content he bought with any other person.

Answer (score 1):

your application folder already define at `context.getFilesDir().getPath()` path application install time and one more thing this folder is hide default. only your application is access

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will check it out.

Comment: what is context?

Answer (score 0):

These are the two most popular file system management and download libraries for react-native:

- [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)
- [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

I use react-native-fetch-blob because it has better support for opening downloaded files and download manager for android. There is also friendly [dir API](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs) with easy access to commonly used folders.